# Remove offset on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, angular-bootstrap

I have div in container that I want to be col-*-8 with offset-2 on medium, large, and extra large screens - this would put it in center of page and smaller with wide, however at same time when screen is small or extra small I want to offset to be removed and col-*-12 div being of full with

I tried with:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
  Some content here...
</div>
```

What I doing wrong ?
Ps. I also using angular on page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `col-xs-offset-0`. it is not necessary.
here is a forked [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dqnadcb/)

Answer (score 0):

The classes that you have there should do the job so long as you have properly wrapped the div in parent `.container` and `.row` div elements. Including those wrappers would look like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
            Some content here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 the syntax is a little bit change

```
col-lg-10 offset-lg-2
```